# Iterator Behavior: Internal Sorting Disregards Original Indexes

Tags: javascript

A curious issue has recently piqued my interest, leaving me scratching my head. When dealing with a provided list that is pre-sorted, such as:

```
  "000": "000",
  "001": "001",
  "002": "002",
  "003": "003",
  "107": "107",
  "108": "108"
```

or

```
  "000": "000 - Roy",
  "001": "001 - James",
  "002": "002 - Ben",
  "003": "003 - Nathan",
  "107": "107 - George",
  "108": "108 - Silus"
```

and attempting to iterate through it using a standard iterator (for our case, Forof), an unexpected behavior arises. Consider the following snippet:

```js
const items = {

  "000": "000",
  "001": "001",
  "002": "002",
  "003": "003",
  "107": "107",
  "108": "108"

}
for (const key in items) {
  if (key) {
    console.log("The Item Yahh", items[key]);
  }

}
```

Surprisingly, the very first index utilized by the iterator is 107, despite the expectation that it should start with 000. According to ECMAScript specifications, this deviation shouldn't occur.

This begs the question: why does the iterator sort in ascending numerical order where 1 precedes 0? This behavior contrasts sharply with observations made when iterating over an array of strings:

```js
const items = [

  "000",
  "001",
  "002",
  "003",
  "107",
  "108"

]
for (const key in items) {
  if (key) {
    console.log("Yahh an Array Item", items[key]);
  }

}
```

In this case, the order remains intact. What could be causing this inconsistency in behavior?

Comment: `107` probably parses as a “number-like” and thus comes first in the iteration, whereas `000` is treated as a string, which come second.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) I don't see answer of this question why it was closed?

Comment: @deceze what about 001 then would it be treated as a string because the first character contains a 0? 

Also not sure who flagged this but the Duplicate issue touches on the general concept of Javascript object property ordering, Im trying to discuss the conditions that make up that ordering so that does not answer my question

Comment: I've added another duplicate which goes into more detail. In the end, it comes down to [CanonicalNumericIndexString](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-canonicalnumericindexstring) in the spec. TL;DR: If the string representation of a number matches the number, it's a number, otherwise it's a string. Since `000` parses to the number `0` and the string representation of `0` (`'0'`) does not match `'000'`, it's a string.

Comment: Not counting symbols, object keys are just strings, but `"000"` and `"0"` are not the same thing. Only `"0"` is considered a "number-like" which comes first, same thing happens to `"107"`. Here's is [an article that demonstrate this behavior better](https://dev.to/frehner/the-order-of-js-object-keys-458d)

Comment: I'll leave my answer here in a gist, I'll add it once the question is reopened. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/0d93e842ec0600c3916668f4373ab6d5

Comment: An object is not a list, it is not sorted! There is no iterator here! Use an array if you need a specific order.